# How to detect and remove a link inside a string in python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have strings which may (or may not) contain links. If the link exist, it is surrounded by  [link] [/link] tokens. I would like to replace those parts with some special token such as  `URL`. and return the corresponding link.

**Example**

Let's assume the function `detect_link` does this:

```
>input= 'The statement [link] http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/sep/9/rob-ranco-texas-lawyer-says-he-would-be-ok-if-bets/ [/link] The Washington Times'
>replacement_token = "URL"
>link,new_sentence = detect_link(input,replacement_token)
>link
'http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/sep/9/rob-ranco-texas-lawyer-says-he-would-be-ok-if-bets/'
>new_sentence
'The statement URL The Washington Times'
```

I searched a little bit and found that Regular expressions can be used to do that. However, I do not any experience with them. Can someone help me about that ?

**EDIT**
Links don't have any constant pattern. It may or may not start with http. It may or may not end with .com etc

Comment: Would this do? https://regex101.com/r/9zpgGy/1

Comment: @Xorifelse It seems working. Do you know how can I integrate it into python code ?

Comment: By using `re`, explained below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a regex pattern for that. I use http://www.regex101.com to play around with regexes.

You can use that pattern to extract things and replace things like so:

```
import re

text = 'The statement [link] http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/sep/9/rob-ranco-texas-lawyer-says-he-would-be-ok-if-bets/ [/link] The Washington Times'

# get what what matched
for mat in re.findall(r"\[link\](.*?)\[/link\]",text):
    print(mat)

# replace a match with sthm other
print( re.sub(r"\[link\](.*?)\[/link\]","[URL]",text))
```

Output:

```
http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/sep/9/rob-ranco-texas-lawyer-says-he-would-be-ok-if-bets/ 

The statement [URL] The Washington Times
```

The pattern I use is non-greedy, so it wont match multiple [link][/link] parts if they occure in one sentence but only the shortest ones:

```
\[link\](.*?)\[/link\]   - matches a literal [ followed by link followed by literal ]
                           with as few things before matching the endtag [/link]
```

Without non-greedy matches you only get one replace for the whole of

```
The statement [link] http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/sep/9/rob-ranco-texas-lawyer-says-he-would-be-ok-if-bets/ [/link] and this also [link] http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/sep/9/rob-ranco-texas-lawyer-says-he-would-be-ok-if-bets/ [/link] The Washington Times
```

instead of two.

---

find all links:

```
import re
text = """
The statement [link] link 1 [/link] and [link] link 2 [/link] The Washington Times
The statement [link] link 3 [/link] and [link] link 4 [/link] The Washington Times
"""

# get what what matched
links = re.findall(r"\[link\](.*)\[/link\]",text)        # greedy pattern
links_lazy = re.findall(r"\[link\](.*?)\[/link\]",text)  # lazy pattern
```

Output:

```
# greedy
[' link 1 [/link] and [link] link 2 ', 
 ' link 3 [/link] and [link] link 4 ']
# lazy
[' link 1 ', ' link 2 ', ' link 3 ', ' link 4 ']
```

The difference is visible if you do not include newlines in the text-to-match - the `(*.)` does not match newlines - so if you have multiple links in a sentence you need a `(.*?)` match to get both as single match instead of getting the whole part matched.

Comment: thank you for your response. What should I do if I want to capture all the links if there exist more than one in a sentence ?

Comment: @zwlayer see edit - with a lazy evaluated pattern `(,*?)` instead of `(.*)`  this will work